# how to use several group by in one query?

Tags: mysql

I have problems with the following code. I want it to return the max temp from a specific zone. Zones are several. I suppose the `AND` is wrong between both group.

```
select max(temperature)
from tempdat
group by tdate having tdate = curdate()
and group having zone having zone ='inne'
```

The database has 4 colums, this query only returns the temperature column, how can i get all columns in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.zone_id,t1.temperature
   from tempdat t1
where
   t1.tdate = curdate()
and t1.temperature = 
   (select max(t2.temperature) from  tempdat t2 
        where t1.tdate = t2.tdate 
        and t1.zone_id = t2.zone_id);
```

Comment: Working with max(temperature) but when using min(temperature) it returns empty.

Comment: SELECT zone, temperature, ttime
FROM tempdat
WHERE tdate = curdate( )
AND zone = 'inne'
AND temperature = (

SELECT min( temperature )
FROM tempdat
WHERE tdate = curdate( )
)
limit 1; The only thing i changed from the MAX query is MAX to MIN. The MAX query is working.

Comment: last condition is missing

Answer (score 0):

Max for each zone for each date -

```
select max(temperature), tdate,zone
from tempdat
group by tdate, zone
```

If you want for a specific zone, for each date try

```
select max(temperature), tdate,zone
from tempdat where zone  ='inne'
group by tdate, zone
```

If you want max for each zone and for curr_date,

```
select max(temperature),zone
from tempdat
where tdate = curdate()
group by  zone
```

If you are applying filters, better apply them in WHERE clause rather than in HAVING clause. Only when you want to apply filters on aggregated data, you need to put them in HAVING clause.

Comment: Works fine, but how do i get the time (ttime) when the max(temperature) was logged? I tried adding ttime in the select row but it returns the fist logged time at that day.

Comment: To get reliable, predictable output, any column which you are selecting, and on which you are not applying an aggregate function (max is the function in this case) should be used in the group by clause too. If you are using a value with the timestamp also, then you have a problem - since the max will apply at the timestamp level.  Is tdate having the time part or just the date?

Comment: Please give table definition and a sample record. That will help clarify things.

Comment: This one: select max(temperature),zone, ttime
from tempdat
where tdate = curdate()
group by  zone; Returns correct max(temperature) 22.250, but wrong  time 00:00:03. Tdate is contains only date aond ttime only time.

Comment: Try something like this - select t1.zone,t1.temperature, t1.tdate, t1.ttime
   from tempdat t1 join 
   (
select max(temperature),zone,tdate  from tempdat where tdate = curdate() group by zone,tdate
) t2 on (t1.zone=t2.zone and t1.temperature=t2.temperature and t1.tdate=t2.tdate)